# High Load on Java Spring boot application increases processing time

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, azure-aks

We have Java Spring boot REST Application running on Azure AKS cluster. While doing load testing on the application ( More than 400 user in a Second) we are seeing the calls between the services and third part services are taking a long time.
We are monitoring the App with Datadog API and below are the
[Normal Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSh1r.png)
[During Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3RNu.png)
We are seeing that when the load increases the application is waiting for a very long duration when it makes a call to another service via rest.
We are seeing this behaviour  for services which are with in the cluster or event third part service on AWS.
Normal load is < 50 users per second, high load is 400 users per second.

My question is is this happening due to network issues or due to the high threads causing the wait.
We are not seeing the CPU going to 100%.
We are running the application in 2 Core CPU with 12 G of ram.